# How to open List view in a specific place of activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment

I want to open the List view from the bottom of screen to almost little high of middle of screen. I have no idea how to do it. I have just idea about it that it could only be done by fragment and I do not know how to use it in my current activity and xml What I want is shown in following picture :

[image]

I hope my question is quite clear. I know How to implement the list view but I do not know ho to implement it in this way I wanted (I mean to appear and disappear with out disturbing other views). this list should overlay other views.

**EDIT**

> including my Xml File so that if you can see what I have done in design

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="content_desc_overlay"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/img_view"

        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_overlay"
        android:src="@drawable/doom"
        android:scaleType="matrix"

        />

</FrameLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open List"
        android:id="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion ? Source code would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is based on the xml design. So you need to show us your xml file.

Comment: wait I am including this , but it is simple

Comment: @Amsheer done take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your list view in a separate blank activity and in the manifest put the theme of activity as dialog

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.EditSignatureActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_signature"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

and on click of open list button start new intent:

```
public void openListButton_OnClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, List.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

don't forget to resize your new listView activity as much as you want its dimensions and add margins to fit the position you need

Comment: would it be transparent ?

Comment: you mean the background of the listview?? if yes, you can simply set the background to smoethng like this color `android:background="#88c2c4c9"` the first 88 is for transparency the rest is for the color, you can change it as you want

Comment: It is giving me following Error. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: yes change your App theme style in the back activity to
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>`
you can find it under res--> values--> styles

Comment: did you  `extends Activity` in your new activity and not ActionBarActivity??

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake

Comment: please tell me how to set its parameters to open like I showed it in picture

Comment: `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88c2c4c9"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp">`
the margin depends on the screen you are using

Comment: try this in the code `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: your answer is working for me, It should be selected as the right answer so far

Answer (score 0):

I will give you sample. You must need to modify. Ask if any doubts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/top_row">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text A" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text B" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_row"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note : You need to load listView with data.